# Create Intent, but leave BottomAppBar visible

Tags: android, android-intent, visibility, bottomappbar

I have a standard Android app with a BottomAppBar, 3 fragments/tabs, a floating action button which opens an Intent. The intent occupies the whole screen and covers the BottomAppBar. Is there a way to make the BottomAppBar visible while the Intent is open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two real ways to do this:

1)Have a BottomAppBar in both Activities.

2)Don't make these things Activities.  Make them Fragments, and have the top level Activity hold the bottom app bar and decide what fragment will display above it.

Really #2 sounds probably better, but it depends on exactly what you're doing.